# debug task skipped on AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm launching a job on AWX that use a project that contains a playbook like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Deploy
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Debug
        debug:
          var: my-var
          verbosity: 4
```

task is skipped and has returned below output:

```
TASK [Debug] *******************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

However when I've launched playbook from my workstation, task is properly executed.

Why task on awx server is skipped? Also I've tried to set limit input field with **localhost** or **localhost,all** or **all** and task still is skipped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I have not set job template verbosity to level 4, debug tasks are skipped when verbosity level doesn't match.